# Use PHP DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile to modify all hrefs and make them absolute

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I'm trying to write a script to parse a web page. Before doing anything with the contents of the page, I would like to transform every link from relative to absolute.

When I try to modify the contents, I get the following error: (the error occurs in the line: $link->getAttribute('href') = $href;)

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

I believe loadHTMLFile() returns an object. I don't know much about working with objects. Is it possible to modify it and return the modified version?

I've considered just turning it into text but that won't work. I need to find the contents of certain elements after transforming the 'href' attributes. I'm using the simple_html_dom.php library to find the elements I need; and it relies on keeping the object in the same format that loadHTMLFile() returns.

```
<?php    
$domain = 'http://www.test.com/'

$doc = new DOMDocument();

@$doc->loadHTMLFile($domain);
$doc = make_absolute($doc);

function make_absolute($obj){
    foreach($obj->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        $href = trim($link->getAttribute('href'));

        if ( (substr($href,0,1) == '/' ) {
            $href = 'http://www.test.com'.$href;
        }

        $link->getAttribute('href') = $href;
    }
    return $obj;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the value of `href=""` attribute, its [`->setAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php):

```
$link->setAttribute('href', $href);
```

Comment: OH duh. I thought the problem was something completely different. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`$link->getAttribute('href')` returns some string, as a result you trying to do something like this:

```
'some string' = 'another string';
```

You should use **set**Attribute instead of getAttribute